# objectdb vs hibernate and mysql on glassfish

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, objectdb

every website I can find seems biased to praised `objectdb` over `hibernate and mysql`. Example, http://www.jpab.org/ObjectDB/ObjectDB/server/Hibernate/MySQL/server.html.

Are there any disadvantages to using `objectdb` instead of `hibernate and mysql` for java web services? I am of course using JPA.

Comment: You mean the website that is owned and written by the ObjectDB developer?

Comment: ObjectDB is a ODBM as Hibernate, MySQL is a RDBMS over which both ObjectDB and Hibernate can run. You are comparing cars with steering wheels and the accepted answer is answering a different question (ODBM vs RDBMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean are there advantages and disadvantages of using an ODBM against an RDBMS ? There are ample refs on the web that address that.

With particular respect to JPA, it is designed around RDBMS syntax, and so it is likely that some query sintaxis will not be fully supported in an object datastore (whether ObjectDB or any other). This may mean that some queries either throw an exception or evaluate in-memory (and that may mean speed). On the other hand it may be quicker at some persistence ops. Obviously you will not get anything like the number of people available who know about that datastore if you have problems, whereas with MySQL there are many thousands.

Also there are many JPA implementations available for persisting to MySQL, and they all have their own advantages and disadvatanges. Hence this questions is way too open ended, and is just going to search for personal opinion rather than anything specific fact based

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am building a rest api. And I am not sure why I should use objectdb, despite all the hypes. My suspicion is based on that I am not able to find any negatives about ObjectDB, which makes no sense to me. I think I will go with MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: He asked about ObjectDB which is an Object database (or object-oriented database), he is not asking about ODBMS vs RDBMS! I think this answer is making a lot of confusion

Comment: Obviously he's asking asking about ObjectDB ... **which is an ODBMS**. Consequently the "benefits" of an ODBMS over an RDBMS apply here and are well understood. There is no confusion (apart from what you have maybe). The answer was marked as accepted a year ago.